# R lapply on multiple columns to Python equivalent?

Tags: python, r

I'm currently trying to find a pythonic way to "translate" the below R code which takes in a dataframe with three columns titled "strikeDeg", "dipDeg" and "rakeDeg" and appends it with three columns:

- rotation = 9-element vector
- pole = 3-element vector
- direction = 3-element vector

This is part of a larger if-loop to parse the original dataframe depending on what columns are not NULL.

```
geoPoleDirectionRotationFromData <- function(dataFrame) {
    newFrame <- emptyDataFrame(nrow(dataFrame))
      # Make rotation, pole, direction from strike, dip, rake.
    newFrame$rotation <- lapply(1:nrow(dataFrame),
                              function(i) geoRotationFromStrikeDipRakeDeg(
                                c(dataFrame[i,]$strikeDeg, dataFrame[i,]$dipDeg, dataFrame[i,]$rakeDeg)))
    newFrame$pole <- lapply(1:nrow(newFrame), function(i) newFrame$rotation[[i]][1,])
    newFrame$direction <- lapply(1:nrow(newFrame), function(i) newFrame$rotation[[i]][2,])
    newFrame
```

The part of the code in question is how can I perform lapply() functions in each of the 3 new columns on the 3 existing columns of the input dataFrame in python? Would I have to create a vector from the existing columns of the dataFrame and apply a map() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just use the `apply` function, and specify `axis` to match the dimension you want to apply it.

you can see an example in the following [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-apply/)

simple example for applying function on column:

```
import pandas as pd

matrix = [(222, 34, 23),
         (333, 31, 11),
         (444, 16, 21),
         (555, 32, 22),
         (666, 33, 27),
         (777, 35, 11)
         ]

# Create a DataFrame object
dfObj = pd.DataFrame(matrix, columns=list('abc'))
print(dfObj)

modDfObj = dfObj.apply(lambda x : x + 10) 
print(modDfObj)
```

I get the following output:

```
     a   b   c
0  222  34  23
1  333  31  11
2  444  16  21
3  555  32  22
4  666  33  27
5  777  35  11

     a   b   c
0  232  44  33
1  343  41  21
2  454  26  31
3  565  42  32
4  676  43  37
5  787  45  21
```

You can see that the only change was in the all the columns and you can easily generalize it to your desire.  (for instance) for applying to a specific column or columns you can change the `apply` line to either options:

```
modDfObj = dfObj.apply(lambda x: x + 10 if x.name == 'b' else x)
modDfObj = dfObj.apply(lambda x: x + 10 if (x.name == 'b' or x.name == 'c') else x)
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I'm just a little confused how to use apply() when the lambda function requires a vector made up of three variables. I've tried to do a list comprehension: newFrame["rotation"] = [geoRotationFromStrikeDipRakeDeg(dataFrame[i]) for i in dataFrame] but i don't think it's correctly indexing the rows

Comment: So you can see a more sophisticated example on how to use `lambda` with `apply` and external function in: https://towardsdatascience.com/apply-and-lambda-usage-in-pandas-b13a1ea037f7